# Custom code to display current time not working

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

```js
//<![CDATA[
var displayCurrentTime = new function() {
  // Get values...
  var sysHour = getHours(); // Get Hours
  var curHour = 0; // Initialize current hour (12 hr format)
  var morningEvening = "AM"; // Initialize AM/PM notation

  if (sysHour < 13) { // If it's in the morning, set time as is.
    curHour = sysHour;
    morningEvening = "AM"
  } else {
    curHour = sysHour - 12; // If it's in the evening, subtract 12 from the value and use "PM"
    morningEvening = "PM"
  }
  var curMins: getMinutes; // Get current minutes...

  // Capture the ID of the notification bar div, and compose a string from the above values.
  var notificationBar = document.getElementById("notificationBar");
  var dateTimeString = curHour + ":" + curMins + " " + morningEvening;


  // All that code above files into this fun stuff.
  notificationBar.innerHTML = dateTimeString;
}

window.setInterval(function() {
  displayCurrentTime();
}, 1000);
//]]>
```

I've been reading up some information and I wanted to create a simple script that grabs the hour and minute, does some calculations to determine if it's AM or PM, creates a string variable from those results, and then slips it inside of a specific DIV element.  It does this every second.

Most of the code I've written seems to make sense based on what I've read.  In the beginning I've tried using function displayCurrentTime() {} as well as what you see below (var displayCurrentTime = new function() {}) and neither seem to work.  I cannot get my text to display in the page.  Note: the ID of the div is notificationBar, just as it is here.

Is there anything in this code that makes no sense, or does this actually warrant posting the full HTML?

Comment: `new function`? Drop the `new`. Also: `var curMins: getMinutes; ` is invalid syntax. Use `=`. Check the console. It should show an error message.

Comment: you have few syntax errors in your code. Also, `getHours()` and `getMinutes()` are methods that are part of `Date` object.

Comment: var curMins = getMinutes();  Use equal sign and, getMinutes is a function, you've forgot to add () at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `new` in front of function that you newly define, you don't instantiate  class.
You have few syntax errors, like `var curMins : ...` instead of `var curMins = ...`.

Also, you cannot use `getHours()` and `getMinutes()` methods, outside of `Date` object:

```js
var displayCurrentTime = function() {
                // Get values...
                var d = new Date();
                var sysHour = d.getHours();    // Get Hours
                var curHour = 0;             // Initialize current hour (12 hr format)
                var morningEvening = "AM";   // Initialize AM/PM notation
                    
                if (sysHour < 13) {          // If it's in the morning, set time as is.
                    curHour = sysHour;
                    morningEvening = "AM"
                } else {
                    curHour = sysHour - 12;  // If it's in the evening, subtract 12 from the value and use "PM"
                    morningEvening = "PM"
                }
                var curMins = d.getMinutes();     // Get current minutes...
                    
                var curSecs = d.getSeconds(); //optionally get seconds too 
                // Capture the ID of the notification bar div, and compose a string from the above values.
                var notificationBar = document.getElementById("notificationBar");
                var dateTimeString = curHour + ":" + curMins + ":" + curSecs + " " + morningEvening;
                    
                    
                // All that code above files into this fun stuff.
        notificationBar.innerHTML = dateTimeString;
            }
                
            window.setInterval(function(){ displayCurrentTime(); }, 1000);
```

```html
<div id='notificationBar'>
Time Here 
</div>
```

See about Date object:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

About functions and anonymous function expression:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#The_function_expression_(function_expression)

Also:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Howto

Comment: My only issue here now, is the fact it doesn't seem to be automatically refreshing.  I see that values less than 10 only show a single digit (I'll correct that easily enough) but that said, how do I get it to actually update?  Seems the code at the bottom to auto run isn't working?  Do I do a self-invoking function (or whatever the correct term is, I just forgot)

Comment: @Anthony, it is auto running, you have setInterval, but keep in mind, that changes are visible only after each minute changed, no matter due to interval. Try adding seconds with `d.getSeconds()`, and you will see it changes

Comment: @Anthony, I have added seconds in my edited example so you can see refreshes

Comment: So it hasn't updated.  It's only working when I reload the page manually... window.setInterval(displayCurrentTime(), 1000);is the code I have, after modifying from the other suggestions... any other changes needed

Comment: @Anthony, did you run code snippet? It should work. Weird

Comment: wait, resolved.  So I removed the function() and the brackets but it seems I needed it.

Or did I JUST need the brackets and no function() in front?

Your snippet ran fine btw.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few syntax errors in your function, I'll get to them one by one:

1. You shouldn't use `new` when declaring a function. Just drop it =) `var displayCurrentTime = function() {`
2. You are trying to assign a value to a variable using json syntax `:` in `var minutes: getMinutes`. You also forgot to execute the function, so try `var minutes = getMinutes();`
3. In (2) I assume you already declared the methods `getHours` and `getMinutes`, but if not, you can call them directly from a new `Date` object:

```
var date = new Date();
var sysHours = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
//...
```

That should do it!

Extra: you can skip adding the `displayCurrentTime` to another function inside the `setInterval` function: `window.setInterval(displayCurrentTime, 1000);`

```js
var displayCurrentTime = function() {
            var date = new Date();           // Get current date object
            var sysHour = date.getHours();   // Get Hours
            var curHour = 0;                 // Initialize current hour (12 hr format)
            var morningEvening;              // No need to initialize
            if (sysHour < 13) {              // If it's in the morning, set time as is.
                curHour = sysHour;
                morningEvening = "AM"
            } else {
                curHour = sysHour - 12;      // If it's in the evening, subtract 12 from the value and use "PM"
                morningEvening = "PM"
            }
            var curMins = date.getMinutes(); // Get Minutes
                
            // Capture the ID of the notification bar div, and compose a string from the above values.
            var notificationBar = document.getElementById("notificationBar");
            var dateTimeString = curHour + ":" + curMins + " " + morningEvening;

            // All that code above files into this fun stuff.
            notificationBar.innerHTML = dateTimeString;
        }
            
        window.setInterval(displayCurrentTime, 1000);
```

```html
<div id='notificationBar'></div>
```